# MSBuild Unknown function 'file::get-checksum'

Tags: c#, msbuild

I'm trying to get the MD5 of a file using MSBuild and is giving the error:

```
C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3614a553d9bd12e6\IntegradorWS.build(488,6):
Unknown function 'file::get-checksum'.
Expression: ${servicos.senha}${file::get-checksum(publicar.zip, 'MD5')}
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Add MSBuild.ExtensionPack from References and .csproj in import:

```
<Import Project="C:\Program Files\MSBuild\ExtensionPack\4.0\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks" />
```

Error this code:

```
<property name="publicar.checksum" value="${servicos.senha}${file::get-checksum(publicar.zip, 'MD5')}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of the property line doesn't look like MSBuild syntax. I did this:

```
 <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.File TaskAction="GetChecksum" Path="test.txt">
   <Output TaskParameter="Checksum" PropertyName="chksm"/>
 </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.File>
 <Message Text="MD5 checksum is: $(chksm)" />
```

The output showed the MD5 checksum of the file:

```
  Getting Checksum for file: test.txt
  MD5 checksum is: 3BAB25A3E651A9E4A00473D2257B99F9
```